# sed: add an unusual header with quotes

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

I have following variables:

```
STR1="CD45RA_naive"
STR2="CD45RO_mem"
STR3="CD127_Treg"
STR4="IL17_Th_stim_MACS"
STR5="IL17_Th17_stim"
names=($STR1 $STR2 $STR3 $STR4 $STR5)
```

and the files with the same names as variables with a ".bed" extension.
in each file I need to add a following header:

```
track name='enhancer region' description='${names[$i]}'"
```

My idea was the following:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#names[@]}; i++))
do
    echo "output/annotation/"${names[$i]}".bed"

    sed -i '' "1 i \track name='enhancer region' description='"${names[$i]}"'" "output/annotation/"${names[$i]}".bed"

done
```

However I get an error:

```
sed: 1: "1 i \track name='enhanc ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command
```

What is a proper way to add a corresponding header to each file (gawk,sed)?

Comment: Does a newline after the ``\`` help?

Comment: Do you use Mac OS X or a BSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically need the line that is inserted for the `i` command to be on its own line.  In other words, you need to add a newline after the backslash.  For example:

```
$ cat input
line 1
$ sed -e '1i\
foo' input
foo
line 1
$ sed -e '1i\ foo' input
sed: 1: "1i\ foo
": extra characters after \ at the end of i command
```